# How to re-submit a Microsoft Edge Add-on if it fails in certification review?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension, microsoft-edge-chromium

I am trying to publish my extension on Microsoft Edge Add-ons. I submitted my package but it failed in the certification review because of a small error in my store listings as flagged in the review report. I fixed the error but I am unsure about how to submit my package again.

1. What should I do to resubmit my extension?
2. Is there any official document that explains how to resubmit an extension that has failed once in review?
3. Will there be an immediate update to the extension once I resubmit or will there be another review cycle?

Answer (score 2):

If your extension failed the certification process, you need to update your extension and resubmit your extension that incorporates the feedback shared in the review report.

**To edit your extension, complete the following steps.**

1. Navigate to your developer dashboard: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/update-extension and choose the extension that failed the certification process.
2. Update either the extension package or the metadata incorporating the feedback received from the certification process. If you update the extension package, ensure that you increase the version in the manifest file.
3. After making changes, choose Save > Publish.

You could also refer to the link here for the same details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/update-extension#update-your-extension-on-the-microsoft-edge-add-ons-store

The above process will initiate a new review with the latest submission.